# How to derive divergence in polar coordinates?

Tags: calculus, vectors

Or more generally, how does one derive the dot product in alternative coordinate systems? Since the unit vectors in polar coordinates are defined as $\hat{\theta}$ and $\hat{r}$. How can the dot product be defined when using these basis vectors without converting them to the cartesian unit vectors?

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3044642/divergence-in-polar-coordinates) answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately i am not familiar with metrics.

Comment: I like to not limit myself to _unit length_ basis vectors. It makes all kinds of formulas look much nicer in the end. It's more natural to let the basis vector $\hat\theta$ at point $(r, \theta)$ have length $r$. It's somewhat like using radians rather than degrees for angle measures because it makes combining calculus and trigonometry much nicer.

Comment: Observe that $\hat r$ and $\hat\theta$ are always orthogonal. That aside, I think you’d be better off applying to chain rule to the definition of $\operatorname{div}$ in the standard basis instead of trying to interpret the mnemonic notation $\nabla\cdot f$ as a “real” dot product.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/586848/265466) might also be helpful, although it derives $\operatorname{grad}$ instead of $\operatorname{div}$.