# Divergence operator in polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates, divergence-operator

Hello  i'm an absolute beginner and i have some problem with del operator in polar coordinate and any help would be appreciated.

del operator in polar coordinate is defined as :
$
 ∇=(\frac{d}{dr}, \frac{1}{r} \frac{d }{d \theta}) 
$

assume a vector field F=(u,v)
then the divergence of  F should be :  $∇.F=(\frac{d}{dr}, \frac{1}{r} \frac{d }{d \theta}).(u,v)=\frac{du}{dr}+\frac{1}{r} \frac{d v }{d \theta}=\frac{1}{r}(r\frac{du}{dr}+ \frac{d v }{d \theta})$
but i see $∇.F=\frac{1}{r}(\frac{d(ru)}{dr}+ \frac{d v }{d \theta})$ every where.

my question is some thing wrong with my product or it shouldn't be treated as a dot product (i read some people telling that divergence is not a real dot product)?

Comment: Hint . You should use the chain rule to express $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ as linear combinations of $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$. The "del" operator in polar coordinates is not what you were thinking.

Comment: You have to note that the basis vectors change in polar coordinates. So $\mathrm{div}\:F
=\nabla\cdot F$ is only true in cartesian coordinates. You can see   the general formula [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3058010/1012221).